# Half spaces union and intersection in R or C++

Tags: c++, r, computational-geometry

I have 2 points:

```
a = c(2,8)
b = c(6,4)
```

Each point is the extreme point of a half-space, i.e. a rectangle closed by the point in the top right angle, and open in the bottom left. 
I need the union of those 2 points, whom the result will be a half-space with 2 extreme points.

The same process is made on the following 2 points:

```
c = c(3,7)
d = c(4,5)
```

Then, I need the intersection of those 2 half-spaces, with the extreme points being

```
e = (4,4)
f = (2,7)
```

So far, I haven't found any package that can do it. Please also note that this is example data, and that more points can be added to the half-spaces (creating a step function bounded on the top right), and that it will go to 5 dimensions in the real data.

Comment: To my understanding a half-space can be expressed as an inequality like $10-x > y$ (correct me if I'm wrong it's been a while since I studied maths). There are a few packages in CRAN that deal with constrained equations. I believe a package like  [`validatetools`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/validatetools/index.html)  can do the job but it depends a lot on how you define your problem.

Comment: From your definition of what a halfspace is, wouldn't the intersection of halfspaces defined by (4,4) and (2,7) just be (2,4)? i.e. halfspace defined by the point which has the minimum coordinates (because you said the point is in the top right) of the two given points?

Comment: It's unclear what is your "half-space"... May be, to add a picture?